# Why would we use blank identifiers in Go?

Tags: go

I'm finding the use of the blank identifier a little hard to understand. I've looked at [effective go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#blank) and understand most of the use cases they describe but then looking at a tutorial I came across this in a route handler function:

```
var person Person
_ = json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&person)
```

in the first line we create a new empty variable of type Person (a struct previously defined) and then I assume that

- `&person` is passing the person var in by reference,
- to be filled with data by the `Decode` function

this function then goes on to perform a few more tasks before encoding and returning a json response.

Why do we need have the decode assigned to a blank identifier? Couldn't we just run `json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&person)` ? if we can't, why not?

Comment: It's not needed there, but the author may have put it there to indicate they are willfully ignoring the error value.

Comment: okay great, does a single blank identifier ignore all return assignments when applied like this?  I thought it would only ignore one of them as in the example of bad practice, `fi, _ := os.Stat(path)`

Comment: I can not honestly vote for closure of this question. The OP is looking for insight into best practices.

Comment: You can only assign one thing per blank identifier, and `Decode` only returns one value. It may usually be bad practice to ignore errors, but in some cases the error simply doesn't matter; perhaps not decoding anything is the error regardless. I think the only really issue here is lack of comments in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're learning golang and asking because you can't identify why this example used this practice.

As @JimB mentioned in comments, the example writer didn't need to do this they're simply ignoring the Error return.

Comment: This answer seems to contain less information than the comment it references.

Comment: thats exactly it, day 1 noob here, as per my comment above does a single blank identifier ignore all return assignments when applied like this? I thought it would only ignore one of them as in the example of bad practice in effective go `fi, _ := os.Stat(path)`

Comment: @pushplaybang: both this and the original question could be answered faster by simply trying them.

Answer (score 1):

The blank identifier `_` can be used to strictly provide the keys in a struct too. See [this](https://developer20.com/golang-tips-and-trics-v/) for reference

Without enforcing

```
type SomeStruct struct {
  FirstField string
  SecondField bool
}

myStruct := SomeStruct{"", false}
```

Enforcing to mention the key for the value (Removes the dependency of ordering the values)

```
type SomeStruct struct {
  FirstField string
  SecondField bool
  _ struct{}
}

// COMPILATION ERROR
myStruct := SomeStruct{"", false}
```

The above will give the error `too few values in SomeStruct literal`

Comment: thank you, while this is informative, it doesn't specifically speak to the question asked.

Comment: I agree, I came here looking at the title of the question. Thought I could contribute something and it would help someone

Comment: But you can still write `myStruct := SomeStruct{"", false, struct{}{}}`… I wouldn't say that technique is "enforcing".